# How to set up SimpleCV on Anaconda (Windows 10)

Tags: python, anaconda, simplecv

I can't figure out how to set up SimpleCV. I [downloaded it](http://simplecv.org/download/), and installed it, but have no idea where to go [from here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvMdv.png) How can I go about setting it up for use with Anaconda?

Comment: What have you tried? The [documentation seems pretty good](http://simplecv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about opening your Anaconda prompt and do

```
pip install simplecv
```

This will install the SimpleCV module to your python environement, making it accessible with `import SimpleCV`

This can be done to any module you want to install. pip makes it really easy.